# Count and Max after values() method on Django query

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-queryset

I have this Django model:

```
class Action(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    game = models.ForeignKey(Game)
    step = models.ForeignKey(Step)
    from_player = models.ForeignKey(Player)
    to_player = models.ForeignKey(Player)
    type = models.ForeignKey(ActionType)
    timestamp = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
```

I want to do the following:

1. Filter on game, step and type
2. Find the player/players how has/have obtained the highest number of actions

to do so I tried:

```
v = Action.objects.filter(game=1, step=2)
v = v.filter(type=3)
v = v.values('to_player').order_by().annotate(count=Count('to_player'))
v = v.annotate(max=Max('count')).filter(count=F('max')) #try to select the max
```

but last line gives me (because line 3 returns a list of dictionaries):

```
Cannot compute Max('count'): 'count' is an aggregate
```

I know that probably something similar has already been answered but Django values() and aggregate() are a bit tricky to me. Which is the right way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get the highest count using Django's [.latest()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.latest) method. Though documented for dates, it also works on strings and integers.

This should get you the Action with the highest to_player count:

```
# combined the filters, no need to separate into two steps
v = Action.objects.filter(game=1, step=2, type=3)
v = v.annotate(count=Count('to_player'))
v = v.latest('count') # will return Action with the highest count
```

Comment: Thanks, but when then query at line 2 is empty `v.latest('count')` gives `DoesNotExist: Action matching query does not exist.`. However with a simple check before it can be avoided. Why this use of `latest()` is not documented? I read its documentation searching for a solution a few hours ago and I discarded it exactly for this reason.

Comment: Yeah you'll have to surround it in a try except. It's not said in the docs but `.latest()` simply adds an ordering on the field you input and selects the first one.

Also, refer to this if you want a more 'documented' approach, the last example looks like what you need [Aggregation Cheat Sheet](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/aggregation/#cheat-sheet)

Comment: What happens when there is more than one record with max value?

Comment: It will only return one, so you could do something like this in order to account for cases where there are 'ties':

`...`

`max = v.latest('count')`

`v = v.filter(count=max)`

Answer (score 0):

The error gives the clue, you should use aggregate instead of annotate for max:

```
v = Action.objects.filter(game=1, step=2)
v = v.filter(type=3)
v = v.values('to_player').order_by().annotate(count=Count('to_player'))
v = v.aggregate(max=Max('count')).filter(count=F('max')) #try to select the max
```

I'm not sure if the last filter would work but worth to try.

Comment: Last line gives `ProgrammingError: syntax error at or near "FROM"
LINE 1: SELECT  FROM (SELECT "game_action"."to_player" AS "to_player...`

Comment: You can't filter an aggregate, but you can filter an annotation.

Comment: The `ProgrammingError` bug is only present in 1.6, and [has been fixed in 1.7](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/23669#comment:5).