# Group by query in Django

Tags: django

I am still in the same problem. I hope you cooperate in the solution. I want to get the result of this query in Django.

```
SELECT city_name, MAX(total_places) total_places
     FROM(SELECT city city_name, COUNT(city) total_places
             FROM Places
             GROUP BY 1) t1
     GROUP BY 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

If I look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23279690/102315), it should be something like:

```py
Places.objects.annotate(total=COUNT('city')).latest('total')
```